# Use logged in users NetworkCredential to connect to web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

This is working code for me

```
      using (var projectProxy = new Project())
        {
            projectProxy.Url = "...vtjbhj/pjipio/project.asmx";
            projectProxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "network");
            return projectProxy;
        }
```

I have binding as

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <!--Used by app for SharePoint-->
        <binding name="secureBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Here I am hard-coding username ,password,network etc.

Instead I should be able to use current logged in users details here.

How can I do that?

I tried

```
projectProxy.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
projectProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

Still it is not working.

Any helps can save my day !

***UPDATE***

*Both client and server are in different machine

*Both client and server are in same domain

*I am getting error message 401-Unauthorized.

Comment: what useraccount is running the program? is it a exe, a web or what is it?

Comment: so have you set up the website (App Pool) with a valid account?

Comment: How can i set up  an app pool

Comment: Where should I set up app pool? at client or server

Comment: Server :-) Take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/383492/Configuring-IIS-for-ASP-NET-Applications-Deploym

Comment: After setting up an app pool what should I do?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Added the error message at the original pot under UPDATE:

Answer (score 0):

why you are not using below solution ?

```
   [WebMethod(Description = "Getfinfo", EnableSession = true)]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]

public string functionname()
{}
```

you just need to maintain user session after that webservice will response only to user who have session

this will work if both the machine have common session